# Regarding Ricci curvature of Markov chains

Tags: pr.probability, riemannian-geometry, markov-chains

In [Ricci curvature of Markov chains on metric spaces](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAB&url=http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~shmuel/QuantCourse%2520/Metric%2520Space/Olliver,%2520Ricci%2520curvature%2520of%2520markov%2520chains.pdf&ei=J2E3Upq0NtODqgHs84G4Bg&usg=AFQjCNGaEq4XpktG0XUApO1d07ro-jsbkA&sig2=5pf6CN_HjKNHrOLyzQJ3Pg&bvm=bv.52164340,d.aWM) Yann Ollivier, defines a coarse Ricci curvature for a Markov chain with transition kernels $\{m_x\}$ defined on a metric space $(X,d)$ as follows: The curvature along $(xy)$ is 
$$
\kappa(x,y) := 1 - \frac{W_1(m_x,m_y)}{d(x,y)},
$$
where $W_1$ is the $\ell_1$ transportation distance between $m_x$ and $m_y$ with transportation cost $d$. The space is positively curved if $\kappa(x,y) \ge \kappa > 0$. Then, it follows that the Markov chain shows contraction (in $W_1$ metric) to a unique invariant distribution, at a geometric rate (at least like $(1-\kappa)^n$). This is Corollary 21 in the paper.

My question is what happens if we only have $\kappa(x,y) \ge \kappa > 0$ for $d(x,y) \ge M$ for $M$ large enoguh. That is, the space is positively curved if $x$ and $y$ are far apart (and maybe negatively curved if they are close.) Can we still show a contraction from any (or a subset) of starting distributions? If not what else is needed to get such a result.

Comment: The closest thing I thought of is, in the case of graphs with relatively large girth (i.e. which locally look like trees) to use as random walk a uniform jump to a ball much larger than girth. That might be useful to apply some of Ollivier's result (e.g. its Mayers theorem, which has a geometrical conclusion). But while having common flavour with your question, it does not answer it of course.

Comment: That is nice example. I have one in mind myself. The situation is not entirely hypothetical.

Answer (score 2):

Just an example to show that you will certainly need something to get the kind of contraction you're after.

Let the space be $\mathbb N\times \{0,1\}$, where the distance from $(n,i)$ to $(m,j)$ is just $|n-m|+|i-j|$. Imagine a kernel which sends everything towards the origin, but leaving you in the same copy of the Markov chain e.g. $(n,i)$ transitions to 
$(\lfloor n/2\rfloor + Q,i)$, where $Q$ is a Poisson random variable. This satisfies the large scale geometric contraction you're looking for, but clearly two distributions on the two parts of the space will never approach each other.

Comment: You could as well set the transition to be deterministic, $(n,i)\mapsto (0,i)$, your example works just as well that way as $W_1(m_x,m_y)\leq 1$ for all $x,y$ in the space.

Comment: @Anthony, thanks. You are right, but this seems to violate a very basic property, say irreducibility (not quite sure if it is called that for a general state space Markov chain). Let us say that starting from any point in the metric space, there is positive chance of getting to any other point in the  next step. I suspect that even this not enough. I was hoping that someone might have an example which actually contracts in some sense, but the whole space is not positively curved.

Comment: @passerby51: as Wasserstein distance is quite stable, it is easy to modify Anthony Quas' example to have an irreducible Markov chain. However, if all you want is to have one example with contraction without positive curvature, this is a different question. Maybe if you said more about what you really want, you would get answers that would be more interesting to you.

Comment: By the way, if you take the nearest-neighbor walk in a finite graph with large girth ($5$ is sufficient if I am not mistaken), then it is not positively curved, but you have good contraction properties.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner, thanks. It would be nice to have an example in which the contraction can be shown by modifying/extending the argument in Ollivier's paper. Still, any example is interesting as long as the proof can be generalized. Do you have a source that shows the random walk you mentioned contracts?

Comment: The contraction is nothing mysterious, when you have a finite graph (take it connected)...

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can establish a geometric bound if your contraction constraint is the other way around, i.e. if $\kappa(x,y) \geq \kappa > 0$ when $d(x,y) \leq M$ for some suitable $M$.  This kind of approach seems to me to generalise the small set coupling constructions for general state space Markov chains to more Wasserstein distances than the classical total variation metric.  It's explained in this paper (and other places most likely):

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-014-9511-z